# npm module will not execute with no such file, but it does exists

Tags: node.js, npm, windows-10, git-bash

Running Windows 10 and git bash.

I am trying to run the webdriver io npm module. It clearly exists on my system, but when I try to run it it will say no such file. I am not having any issues with npm itself.

Any ideas what is wrong?

```
usery@AUS-LT-384 MINGW64 ~/github/e2e-temp (master)
$ lr ./node_modules/.bin/wdio
-rw-r--r-- 1 user 1049089 23 Mar 27 09:15 ./node_modules/.bin/wdio

user@AUS-LT-384 MINGW64 ~/github/e2e-temp (master)
$ ./node_modules/.bin/wdio wdio.conf.js
./node_modules/.bin/wdio: line 1: ../webdriverio/bin/wdio: No such file or directory

user@AUS-LT-384 MINGW64 ~/github/e2e-temp (master)
$ npm -v
5.6.0
```

Comment: ./node_modules/.bin/wdio: line 1: ../webdriverio/bin/wdio: No such file or directory

shows that ./node_modules/.bin/wdio is executable but it searches for ../webdriverio/bin/wdio. Do you have ../webdriverio/bin/wdio?

Comment: No,  why is it going one parent up to execute?

Comment: does --help work?

Comment: no, same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably were installed this package via another system ( linux maybe ) or WSL ( Windows subsystem for Linux: Bash on windows ); This way npm executables ( `/node_modules/.bin` directory content ) could not be run.

Reinstalling the package by first uninstall it via `WSL`:

```
npm uninstall wdio
```

then install via `git-bash`:

```
npm install wdio
```

should eliminate the problem. If not try to install the package via **Windows terminals**( CMD or PowerShell ). this way in `./node_modules/.bin/` directory you should see a `wdio.cmd` file beside `wdio` file and your executable is ready:

```
user@AUS-LT-384 MINGW64 ~/github/e2e-temp (master)
$ ./node_modules/.bin/wdio -v
v4.12.0
```

Comment: No, it can not be WSL. It has to be native in Windows. The above will not work, Window does not follow the paths of the npm modules.

Comment: @dman, Windows will follow the path if it could find `wdio.cmd` file beside `wdio` file in `.bin` directory. and package should be installed via CMD or PowerShell or git-bash for this file to be generated. you should first uninstall package via `WSL` and then reinstall it via `git-bash` or `CMD` or `PowerShell`

Answer (score 1):

If  you are using 5.x.x then install cli first

npm i --save-dev @wdio/cli

Answer (score 0):

If you use package.json you could include scripts and make it easier to run

```
"scripts": {
  "tests": "wdio wdio.conf.js"
}
```

and run them with

```
npm run tests
```