# after npm install webdriverio ./node_modules/.bin/wdio: No such file or directory

Tags: node.js, appium, wdio-jasmine

I cannot find node_modules/.bin/wdio after having installed on W10.
So, I cannot run Appium tests
Thanks for any support
Lorenzo

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/49517508/10357400](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49517508/10357400) I think this answer is similar with your question. in this answer, question solved with `npm uninstall wdio` and `npm install wdio`

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thanks for the link.